# build.js error when using VueJS with Django

Tags: python, django, vue.js, webpack, django-templates

I'm trying to add VueJS to my Django project using webpacks. I created the vue frontend folder in my Django directory, everything works when i run `npm run dev`, and i can see the default Vue template.

The problem is that i keep getting in my console the error GET `http://localhost:8000/frontend/dist/build.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

When i run my Django project. Instead of seeing the Vue default page as well, i only see a blank page and that error in my console.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
      entry: './src/main.js',
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8000/frontend/dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
      },
```

And here are my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [    
{        
'BACKEND': 
'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',        
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'main/templates')],
....

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)


WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        #'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/dist',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/webpack-stats.json'),
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE:': ['.+\.hot-update.js', '.+\.map']

    }
}
```

And here is what my folder looks like

```
 myfolder > frontend > dist > build.js
```

Can someone help me finding the issue here?

Comment: When you're hitting your django server (localhost:8000) with the path **/frontend/dist/build.js** it will look it up in your urls.py and since it's not there Django will return a 404 not found. You need to put your frontend inside your `assets` folder so build.js will be fetch with the URL **/static/assets/frontend/dist/build.js** from the path **/assets/frontend/dist/build.js**

Comment: Or add the **frontend** directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS` but still make sure the url is **/static/frontend/dist/build.js** since all static files must start with the `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: @dirkgroten just one thing, the Django server is http://127.0.0.1:8000, the Vue server is localhost

Comment: That’s usually the same unless you changed the hosts file. Use a different port.